# How do I show a specific blog post by it's ID when clicking show more button on a blog post in my laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set up a small Laravel application, where I have blog posts and when I click on `show more`, I'll display the blog from it's specific ID.

This are my routes:

```php
Route::get('blog', [BlogController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('blog-single/{blog}', [BlogController::class, 'showMore']);
```

The `{blog}` slug in the blog-single route should take an `id` as a parameter in `showMore` method and find the `blog` with the matching id from the `Blog` model, as I've added here.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Blog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function show() {
        return view('blog', [
            'blogs' => Blog::take(5)->latest()->get(),
        ]);
    }
    
    public function showMore($id) {
        $blog = Blog::find($id);
        return view('blog-single', [
            'blog' => $blog,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My blogs are in `blog.blade.php` and they are fetched dynamically from the database as it is shown in `show` method from `BlogController`:

```html
<div id="body">
    <h1><span>blog</span></h1>
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach($blogs as $blog)
                <li class="blog-post">
                    <a href="blog-single" class="figure">
                        <img src="{{asset('/storage/app/public/product/stach2.jpg')}}" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div>
                        <h3>{{$blog->title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{$blog->body}}</p>
                        <a href="blog-single{{'/'}}{{$blog->id}}" class="more">read this</a>
                    </div>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get routed to `blog/blog-single/$id`, but it's also displaying a `404` page. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Your HTML is not correctly formatted... you are missing a closing `li`... also a `span` inside an `h1` without context ? Also, read the documentation... no need to do `$blog = Blog::find($id)` when you can simply use [`implicit binding`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)...

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of `href` will add current url.

So Change this line

```
 <a href="blog-single{{'/'}}{{$blog->id}}" class="more">read this</a>
```

instead of that use

```
 <a href="{{url('blog-single/',[$blog->id])}}" class="more">read this</a>
```

Also better to create route names like below

```
Route::get('blog-single/{blog}',[BlogController::class,'showMore'])->name('blogSingle');
```

then in blade file

```
 <a href="{{route('blogSingle',$blog->id)}}" class="more">read this</a>
```

Comment: Author, read more about [`url`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url) helper please. The documentation is your friend...

Comment: @matiaslauriti.thanks.always you are trying  to improve others answers. great .may god bless you :)

Comment: Thank you for helping everyone, I open questions and see you have already answered them, that is awesome !